# htaccess RewriteCond not working after forcing https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have some rules that deny access to a contact form from certain IP addresses as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#restrict access to contact form
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.(index.php/)?contact(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^81\.136\.137\.239
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Before I put the https rewrite in the restrictions to the contact form worked OK.
After forcing all traffic to https I am able to get to the contact form even from IP addresses specifically restricted.

Is there something in the REQUEST_URI line that is not picking up https connections? (I would like it to restrict access on both http and https if possible but if not then just https)

Comment: i may confused ,regardless of http&https, do you want to restrict this IP only from accessing contact folder ?

Comment: there are other IPs too but I only showed one for the example. I want to restrict access to the contact form over https and if possible http as well

Answer (score 0):

Go to contact **folder** and make `.htaccess` and put the following code inside it :

```
deny from 81.136.137.239
```

if you have more IP add them like example above

> update

**If it is file try this :**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  contact
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^81\.136\.136\.239 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

For more IPs :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  contact
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^81\.136\.136\.239  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^81\.136\.136\.230  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^81\.136\.136\.220
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Comment: there is no contact folder - it's a dynamic URL. The htaccess is in the site root.

Comment: why will "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  contact" work on https and "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.(index.php/)?contact(.*) [NC]" doesn't ?